# Extract First n Words From String jQuery, Wordpress Style Excerpt In jQuery (x Number Of Words

Tags: jquery, wordpress, extract

I have a little jQuery snippet that works, but in order to improve my JS, I'd like suggestions on how to improve its efficiency.

This function shortens a WordPress Excerpt. It takes the original WordPress Excerpt and extracts the first 40 words, that's the part I care about. After that, it adds the 'Continue Reading' link at the end of the original Excerpt and adds it to the end of the truncated version.

Again, I just wondered what would be a faster/more concise way to return the truncated excerpt. I tried 'slice' and got a bunch of commas.

```
jQuery('.page-id-7 .promo_slider_excerpt').each(function (i) {
    var s = jQuery(this).html();
    var sw = s.split(' '); // separate contents into array of words
    var t = [];
    var v;
    if (sw.length > 40) {
        var a = jQuery(this).children('a'); // this is the Continue Reading link
        for (v = 0; v < 40; v++) {
            t = (t + ' ' + sw[v]); // Build the shortened excerpt (this is the part I wanted to improve)
        }
        t = (t + ' ' + a[0].outerHTML); // Add the Continue Reading onto the end
        jQuery(this).html(t);
    } else {
        t = s;
        jQuery(this).html(t);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first forty words and the continue reading link, I'd suggest:

```
var s = jQuery(this).text(),
    fortyWords = s.split(' ').slice(0,39).join(' '),
    link = document.createElement('a'),
    linkText = document.createTextNode('continue reading');
link.href = 'http://path.to.article/';
link.appendChild(linkText);
$(this).text(fortyWords).append(link);
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BqQF8/).

---

**Edited** in response to further questions from OP (in comments, below):

> 1: Is there a way in Firebug to note the -efficiency- of one technique vs. another? IOW: your example looks good, but can I compare it's memory and speed vs my for loop?

I honestly don't know, I'm afraid I don't really use Firefox at all and, while I use Chromium almost exclusively, I've not worked with it long enough to discover the profiling tools for memory usage or speed.

There is, however, [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/), which will allow you to run tests to show the speed of operation of particular approaches; though it doesn't touch on memory-usage at all.

> 2: My version uses the `.html()` method and `.outerHTML` property. I keep seeing posts on the web that these are not -always- reliable. Is that some holdover from IE6? My users are all pretty current so I wonder why you choose to use `.text()` and then append a node?

`html()` is a good approach to use, but ideally to be used only if you want to work with the html, in a string format; in the above case it seemed easier to work with strings since all I really wanted to work with was the text-string. Had there been other elements within the element whose `text()` I was manipulating, then I'd've had to use `html()` otherwise those elements would have been over-written when writing/replacing the text into the DOM.

I seem to recall not having had much success using `outerHTML` historically, and, frankly, empirically. So I only rarely think to use it, though it is, simply, a matter of personal preference. As to its being a holdover from IE 6? I'm unsure; I wouldn't be surprised, but I don't know at all, unfortunately.

I chose to use `text()` because I was, as noted, working with text; and then I appended the node, separately, in `html()` because I was inserting an html node. Had I used passed the same contents entirely with `html()` then it would, I think, have worked. But, again, just personal preference and, I think, it makes it clear whether I'm manipulating/working with text or html.

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com//).
  - [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- 'Plain' non-library JavaScript:

  - [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:document.createTextNode).
  - [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Thanks. That works---and clears up how to join the wordss. Coming from C, JS often seems a bit odd to me. If I may I have a couple of follow-ups:
1. Is there a way in Firebug to note the -efficiency- of one technique vs. another? IOW: your example looks good, but can I compare it's memory and speed vs my for loop?
2. My version uses the .html() method and .outerHTML property. I keep seeing posts on the web that these are not -always- reliable. Is that some holdover from IE6? My users are all pretty current so I wonder why you choose to use .text() and then append a node?
THANKS! ---JC

Comment: Oh, don't worry, JavaScript seems to seem quite strange to almost everyone at one time or another. You do, however, get used to it over time. But only ever until the *next time*...and, if I've helped, I'm glad to have done so! Feel free to raise your follow-up questions (we're always glad to help), provided you search the site first to make sure they're not duplicates, or they raise different points than previous questions.

Comment: Man you type a lot faster than me. Plz see my 2 follow-up questions. Thanks again!

Comment: What can I say? I've had practice! Incidentally, if you'd consider your question 'answered,' please consider checking the tick-mark shape besides the answer that most helped. (Not necessarily mine, just the one that most helped you to answer your question/solve your problem.) Ah, they're in your first comment. Give me a few minutes...

Answer (score 0):

JQuery shouldn't be used for this. You can modify your excerpt however you need using filters. Let the server do the work:

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_format');
function new_excerpt_format($text)
{
    global $post;
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if(!$text)
    {
        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = strip_shortcodes($text);
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

        $exceptions = ''; //PRESERVE CERTAIN TAGS, ADD/REMOVE AS NEEDED (ex: <p>,<a>,<em>,<strong>,<br>)
        $text = strip_tags($text, $exceptions);

        $maxCount = 55; //DEFAULT WP WORD COUNT, INCREASE/DECREASE AS NEEDED
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $maxCount);

        $moreText = '.... <a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More &gt;&gt;</a>'; //CUSTOM MORE TEXT, CHANGE AS NEEDED
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', $moreText);

        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length+1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if(count($words) > $excerpt_length)
        {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text.$excerpt_more;
        }
        else
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
```

Just add this to your functions.php file and it should take care of everything you need. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I can't use this here because what I'm doing is excerpting from an Excerpt. IOW: I'm trying to get a substring of the already customised excerpt.

Comment: Well, you CAN use it, but it would mean overwriting - or commenting out - any existing excerpt filters. I'm just of the belief that using jQuery for non-jQuery-related problems is bad practice, so this was an alternative.

Comment: That's not to say that the answer by @DavidThomas isn't useful. If his answer solves your problem and helps you gain a better understanding of jQuery, then please accept his answer.

Comment: Don't get me wrong... I -am- appreciative. My main goal is digging more into JS. On this site.. as with a lot of projects I do.. I am encouraged to -add- to, but not -change- if possible. If that makes sense.

Comment: No, I understand completely. Don't worry about it. The purpose of SO is to learn, and if a Javascript/jQuery answer enables you to learn Javascript/jQuery even more deeply and on a more fundamental level, then by all means, pick the answer that suits your needs.